# Making a list with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an app that allows users to list movies. I have my Javascript working, but it's only letting me add one item. How can I change it so I can add multiple inputs to be posted?

In my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="movies.css">
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Favorite Movies</h1>
  <input type="text" id="movie" placeholder="Movie">
  <button id="enter">Enter</button>
  <div id="list">Chosen Films:</div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="movies.js"></script>
</body>
```

and my Javascript:

```
$("#enter").click(
   function() {
     var movie = $("#movie").val();
     var list = (movie);
     $('#list').html(list);
 });
```

Comment: Do you want them to be able to enter like a comma separated list in the text box and then add all those individually to your list?

Comment: It might be useful to show responders what sort of input you're expecting and then what you expect your output to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.html()` jQuery function replaces the entire DIV content with the value. Try using `.append()` or `.prepend()` jQuery function to add content to the DIV.

Assuming you are entering the movie one by one.

```js
$("#enter").click(
  function() {
    var movie = $("#movie").val();
    var list = (movie);
    $('#list').append('<p>' + list + '</p>');
  });
```

```css
p { background-color: lightgrey; margin: 1px; padding-left: 5px; color: blue; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="movies.css">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <title>
    Hello World
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Favorite Movies</h1>
  <input type="text" id="movie" placeholder="Movie">
  <button id="enter">Enter</button>
  <div id="list">Chosen Films:</div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: we got some magic happening with append. Now, it seems like the listed items are a bit cluttered together (ex. XmenAnchormanDespicableMe). Any way I can space them out a bit?

Comment: @T.Jackson Do you enter the movie names one by one.. or all together? If one by one.. the above solution should work as I added a para tag when appending to the div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your list outside of the click handler.

```
var list = [];
$("#enter").click(
   function() {
     var movie = $("#movie").val();
     list.push(movie);
     $('#list').html(list);

 });
```

Also the text in list will get overwritten:

```
<div>Chosen Films: <span id="list"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a global javascript variable, one that is outside the scope of the function you've created to keep track of the list of items.

Take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Each time you add a movie, you'll add that object to this global array and then you'll need to update the list html with the array values.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently replacing the content with new content, when you should append the new content instead.  Add a new div inside your list div, like so:

```
<div id="list">Chosen Films:<div id="mylist"></div></div>
```

and then append your items to it.

```
$('#mylist').append(list);
```

[JS Fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/xjxeentL/).

Comment: my Fiddle example shows one way to handle the formatting of the movie list items.